# Ruby HTTP client that can process Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, http

I would like to access a website that uses Javascript to set a cookie. The cookie is required for the pages I want to visit.

I found that firewatir can do it, but this requires attaching to actual firefox browser. Are there any solutions that can work without UI running?

Comment: So you like to screen scrape a site that tries to protect itself from it? :)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jbarnette/johnson

Comment: All implementations I found in the past really need browser libraries, sometimes there are headless libs they can use, but have no experiences with them.

Comment: If your really interested, you should try out [selenium-webdriver](http://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver). Selenium is also usable by Capybara (mostly used in conjunction with cucumber to do BDD). Be aware: You **need** browsers/browser libs!

Comment: If you want to code a solution: maybe the gem [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) can help you. Then you could do the following: grab the HTML, search for every javascript stuff, execute this with _therubyracer_. Of course, you also need something, which helps you with the DOM. The final result will be a Ruby Browser! :-) If you do that, everybody will thank you evermore!

Comment: I found htmlunit (for Java), and then this article: http://blog.deepcore.gr/?p=70. I plan to try it

Comment: @asaaki, the library will not help if Javascript tries to place a cookie.

Comment: @mbdev, not? would be bad not to have a possibility to catch cookies via JS.

Comment: @asaaki since you would execute the Javascript with a separate process then the browser. 'therubyracer' will not be able to inform the browser to set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

[Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) might be able to do this.

Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it don't. What makes you think Mechanize has a JavaScript engine?

Comment: The Mechanize library is used `for automating interaction with websites`. Mechanize automatically stores and sends cookies, follows redirects, and can follow links and submit forms. Form fields can be populated and submitted. Mechanize also keeps track of the sites that you have visited as a history.